# Get Component/entity model from the component tcm id

Tags: dxa, web8.5, dxa-java, dxa-2.0

If I have a component id (for example tcm:9-123), is there a way to get its content? How can this be achieved in java ?

Comment: Is that components are DCP?

Comment: No, not DCP.  We have based it on dxa's webapp-java project

Comment: Did you mean, if we are using DCP model to assemble content from the Content Data Store, then yes.

Comment: AFAIK - Yes, with DCP you can able to get component MVCData

Comment: Can you share some code, please, in java

Comment: Take a look at the ContentProvider.populateDynamicList  and getEntityModel methods here. https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-java/blob/1610c7be29c038ffebf340bb8c44c5046de607cf/dxa-framework/dxa-tridion-provider/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/tridion/mapping/impl/DefaultContentProvider.java#L206

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want to achieve, exactly. Can you edit the question and elaborate?

Comment: @RickPannekoek, I have edited the question. Hope it is clearer.

Answer (score 3):

In general, you can’t get the content of Components separately on the CD side.

You can get the content of a Dynamic Component Presentation, though. In DXA, DCPs are represented as Entity Models with an ID like `<ComponentID>-<TemplateID>`. For example: `123-234` for a DCP of Component `tcm:x-123` rendered with Template `tcm:x-234-32`.

You can use `ContentProvider.getEntityModel` for this purpose.